# Send public message including sender Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm starting with `socket.io` and I can send private messages but How I can send a message to all,
At the following code(its for test purpose) the first user receives a private message every time an user is connected , How I can broadcast all the message to all clients including the sender?

this is the client

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.emit('user_join', { username:'{{username}}'});
socket.on('private',function(data){
    alert(data);
});
socket.on('message',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

and this is the server

```
var connectedUsers = []

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('user_join', function(msg){
    connectedUsers[msg.username] = socket;
    connectedUsers['aaa'].emit('private','private message');
    socket.emit('message','public message');
  });
  console.log(connectedUsers.keys());
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Comment: Try using broadcast on io. Follow this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_broadcasting.htm#:~:text=Broadcasting%20means%20sending%20a%20message%20to%20all%20connected%20clients.&text=We%20can%20send%20the%20message,we%20can%20use%20the%20io.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is good https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

There's lots of variations, but I think you're looking for:

```
  io.emit('an event sent to all connected clients');
```